# Google Column Chart cropping the bars

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to display data using Google's Column chart. I tried displaying bars not stacked but it would not display one bar from both ends. Then i changed the property `isStacked` to `true`, it displays all the bars but it crops the bar at the both ends.

[image: Google Column Chart]

How can i fix this issue?

I was playing around with the options but nothing seems to work.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawSizeChart);
    var d = 0;
    function drawSizeChart() {

        $.post('/metrics/SiteResourceChart', { fnsId: "@Model.FnsId", regionId: selectedValue },
            function (data) {
                if (Object.keys(data).length !== 0) {
                    var tdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    tdata.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                    for (var p = 0; p < data.length; ++p) {
                        tdata.addColumn('number', data[p][0].PathName);
                    }

                    d = data[0].length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
                            var date = new Date(parseInt(data[i][j].CreatedAt.substr(6)));
                            var rCount = data[i][j].ResourceCount;
                            if (i === 0)
                                tdata.addRow([date, rCount, null]);
                            else
                                tdata.addRow([date, null, rCount]);
                        }
                    }


                    var options = {
                        title: 'Resource Count',
                        titleTextStyle: { fontSize: 20 },
                        isStacked: true,
                        bar: { groupWidth: '20%' },
                        chartArea: { left: '50' },
                        hAxis: { viewWindowMode: 'maximized' }

                        //legend: { position: 'none' }
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('site_size_chart'));
                    chart.draw(tdata, options);
                }
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess a quick solution would be to define your first column as 'string' instead of Date and leave the hAxis.viewWindowMode as default. Otherwise, you should configure [hAxis.viewWindow](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) object (i.e., min/max values).

Comment: I fixed it. I changed the package to `columnchart` and it fixed it. Thanks anyways :-)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. What I did is that I added dummy data with a 0 value one day before the first date and one day after the last date in order to achieve the desired result.

Using the columnchart package wasn't a solution for me because I had days without data but wanted to keep the time axis proportional.